# Where is LibUsbDotNet.dll?

Tags: .net, usb

The first `LibUsbDotNet 2.2.8 Help` example requires project reference LibUsbDotNet.dll. The example code is:

```
using LibUsbDotNet;
using LibUsbDotNet.Info;
using LibUsbDotNet.Main;
namespace Examples
{
    internal class ShowInfo
    {
        public static UsbDevice MyUsbDevice;
        ...
```

Trying to find LibUsbDotNet.dll using google or here at stackoverflow is unclear at best. Using the LibUsbDotNet_Setup.2.2.8 installer installs the LibUsbDotNet Help but not LibUsbDotNet.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just installed LibUsbDotNet myself and found that the DLL should be located in C:\Program Files\LibUsbDotNet assuming you did the "full installation" (default options) when you installed it. If you checked only the documentation and not the runtime, it will not have been placed there.
[image: Location of LibUsbDotNet]

Comment: Updated answer --- Tried it myself and found it there C:\Program Files\LibUsbDotNet

Comment: SOB! There it is. Thanks a million!